# How to assign an id to an HTML <li> element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `<li>` element that needs to be assigned an `id="onlink"` attribute when the user clicks on the specific `<li>` . How to do it using Javascript?

Comment: `li.onclick = function() { li.id = 'onlink' }`

Comment: What do you plan to do with the ID once you've assigned it?

Comment: I wish to do some changes in the CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `id` property of an element by using `element.id='newid';`

in your case:

```
<script>
    function changeID(obj) {
        obj.id = 'onlink';
    }
</script>

<li onclick='changeID(this);'>text</li>
```

Comment: this isnt valid html

Comment: how should I do it if I don't have an id assigned to it initially?

Comment: I'm sorry but your question wasn't so clear to begin with. Now I undertstand, see updated answer

Comment: @Jonasw Why is that?

Comment: @KobyDouek referred to your first version. still bad style to use inline js

Comment: @lmgguy Happy to help and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#pages li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'onlink'+(i+1));
});
```

```css
#onlink1{
color:green;
}

#onlink2{
color:red;
}

#onlink3{
color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pages">
    <li class="something"><a href="#"></a> 1</li>
    <li class="something"><a href="#"></a> 2 </li>
    <li class="something"><a href="#"></a> 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OP is not using JQuery

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #text{
    font-size:40px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <li>
    I am a LI element
    </li>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("LI")[0];
        x.setAttribute("id", "text");
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This HTML is invalid and unusable.

Comment: @Rob why it is invalid??

Comment: *try this* is a really good explanation, and *x* is a real good variable name. and what has css to do with the question?

Comment: A `<li>` element must be enclosed within a `<ul></ul>` or `<ol></ol>`  element and can never stand alone.

Comment: run this script on w3schools you will find out the use of css, and li can stand alone